# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named MyPersistenceUnit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, servlets

I've been looking for a solution to this issue for a long time and have given up.
I tried almost every way possible and still no use. I know this might be a duplicate but trust me, I tried almost every way possible.

In my servlet project with Maven, I've been facing this `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named MyPersistenceUnit` exception. Even though I've looked into almost every possible solution, nothing helped, unfortunately.

here is my `persistence.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_1.xsd"
             version="3.1">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- Specify entity classes -->
        <class>com.example.Student</class>
        <class>com.example.Accounts</class>


        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Network2HW"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and here is my DAO class where the issue is present.

```
package com.example.networksiihw;

import com.example.Accounts;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
import java.util.List;

public class AccountsDAO {

    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit");

    public void addAccounts(Accounts accounts) {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

        try {
            transaction.begin();
            entityManager.persist(accounts);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }

    public Accounts getAccountsById(Long id) {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        Accounts accounts = entityManager.find(Accounts.class, id);
        entityManager.close();
        return accounts;
    }

    public List<Accounts> getAllAccounts() {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        List<Accounts> accountsList = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Accounts a", Accounts.class).getResultList();
        entityManager.close();
        return accountsList;
    }

    // Add additional methods for update and delete if needed
}
```

and here is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>NetworksIIHw</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>NetworksIIHw</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>dotenv-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I don't know what I'm missing honestly. If there is any extra things for me to provide please ask and I'll provide any extra information that can be helpful

Comment: Where is your `persistance.xml` located?

Comment: it was auto generated in its default path in the META-INF directory, persistence unit is clearly shown in my IDE within the project structure, I use IntelliJ Ultimate

Comment: try using a final version of hibernate like **6.2.7.Final**

Comment: nope, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how important it is for you to stick to `jakarta` and other dependencies, but I created here an example using `hibernate-core`: [stackoverflow-persistence-xml](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-persistence-xml).

When I was working out the example, I noticed that the provider in your `persistence.xml` is

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Depending on the exact Hibernate version you use, it could be sufficient to change to

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

If it doesn't do the trick, you can use the example in the GitHub repo.

Comment: tried changing the package name and ended up with an error that suggested I create the package and class within my project. Also, the link you provided lead me to a 404 page so I'd appreciate it if you provided the file as a code in the answer for me to try

Comment: Apologies, forgot to put the repository on public. Note that when you try it out, you'll need to change the username and password of the local mysql user.

Comment: I tried and I got this exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Persistence`

also I got an error at this line `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`
where it says `Cannot resolve class 'HibernatePersistence' `
I checked here https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-no-persistence-provider 
before and it was mentioned that we use this if we have hibernate version 4.2 or older

Comment: The example in the repository doesn't use jakarta anymore.

Comment: apparently, I have to use it since I'm using a Java servlet project. And these days java uses jakarta package I guess, correct me if I'm wrong please I'm still new to all this Java servlet thing

Comment: I'd like to ask something
does my Java version affect this whole thing or not?

Comment: I don’t think your Java version is creating the error. How is the servlet related to the use of jakarta persistence? If you provide a bit more code, we might be able to figure out what’s wrong.

Comment: I removed jakarta persistence dependency and modified the version for hibernate according to the example you provided and all is good in the context of the server still works..but the exception remains there. For extra and more context.
my intention was to build APIs with java servlet to communicate with MySQL database using ORMs. and this is a first time I take such a task so I'm feeling lost tbh.
can you please suggest what code can I provide to help figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible to upload the entire code to a public GitHub repository?

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting..I got a bit busy with other Homeworks. here is the link

https://github.com/HuangLinBao/NetworksHttpHw

Comment: @HuangLinBao, probably your repository is still private. I got a 404.

Comment: sorry for that.. changed the visibility to public, you can check it out now